# Functional way of inserting elements into a list

Tags: python, functional-programming, coding-style

In Python, it's usually neat to write `[f(i) for i in range(n)]`. I wonder if  there is a way to do something like `[A.append(f(i)) for i in range(n)]` or `[A.insert(g(i),f(i)) for i in range(n)]`.

Comment: It's not "always neat", in fact most of time it's kind of dirty

Comment: The docs specifically discourage using list comprehensions for side effects. Just write the for loop.

Comment: If you are using `.append`, or `.insert`, then you aren't using functional programming anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It is really not elegant to write `[A.append(f(i)) for i in range(n)]` as it would confuse readers what you are trying to do.

`[A.append(f(i)) for i in range(n)]` can be better written as

```
A.extend([f(i) for i in range(10)])
```

And `[A.insert(g(i),f(i)) for i in range(n)]` would look better and comprehensible when written as

```
for i in range(n):
    A.insert(g(i),f(i))
```